# How can I set timeout for redirected or for new opened page on other server?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to redirect my page to other page like to google.com or to open google.com as  additional page in the browser.

There is any way to close other opened google-page (if it was opened as a new page) or return to my page (if my page was redirected to google-page) after 10 minutes of timeout?

I tried with $_SESSION, it didn't work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to return to your page if you redirect.  The browser is no longer on your page, and as such as far as the browser is concerned, it's gone.

As for opening another window, it should be possible to set a timer to check if the other page is loaded, but there could be security concerns if that page is on another domain.